# Can't mock unitOfWork and no interfaces of services

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following classes

```
namespace Foo.Bar.Services    
{    
    public abstract class Service    
    {    
        public Service(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)    
        {    
            this.UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;    
        }
        protected IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; private set; }    
    }  
}

using...

namespace Foo.Bar.Services    
{    
    public class ControlService : Service    
    {    
        ...    
        private readonly IRepository<GroupStructure> groupStructures = null;

        public ControlService(IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow)
        {    
           ...
           this.agencyGroupStructures = this.UnitOfWork.GetRepository<AgencyGroupStructure>();    
        }

        public Tuple<bool, int> HasExternalImage(int branchId)
        {
            var externalResultList = from a in this.Structures.Table
                                    where a.GroupID == branch.GroupID
                                        && (a.AreExternalRequired == true)
                                        && (a.ProductTypeID == ETourType.Trailer)
                                        && !a.Deleted
                                    select a;
            return (some logic based on above...)
        }    
}
```

and test

```
namespace ControlTests    
{    
    [TestFixture]    
    public class Control    
    {    
        //unable to create service due to being abstact  
        [Test]    
        public void TestMethod1()    
        {    
            ******Changed here******
            var Mock = new Mock<GroupStructureService> { CallBase = true };    
            var fakeControl = new ControlService(Mock.Object)

            var sut = fakeControl.HasExternalImage(1249);

            Assert.That(sut.Item1, "true");    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Running the above with NUnit and Moq gives the following message:

> Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can
>   not instantiate proxy of class: Foo.Bar.Services.ControlService.
>   Could not find a parameterless constructor.

I've tried a few things but I can't get this previously untested app to create a mock object to test

> Edit, thanks.  So I've changed it to use the ControlService and mock 1
>   dependancy.  But its error is that it cant convert from
>   ....GroupStructure to Foo.Bar.IUnitOfWork

Comment: The error is accurate as the class needs the `IUnitOfWork`

Comment: Why are you mocking that class to begin with? You normally do no mock the class under test. Mock its dependencies and inject that into an instance of the class under test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the system under test is not mocked. Mock its dependencies and inject that into an instance of the class under test

```
[TestFixture]    
public class Control { 

    [Test]    
    public void TestMethod1() {
        //Arrange
        var repository = new Mock<IRepository<GroupStructure>>();
        //...Set up the repository behavior to satisfy logic

        var uow = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        uow.Setup(_ => _.GetRepository<AgencyGroupStructure>())
            .Returns(repository.Object);

        var sut = new ControlService(uow.Object);
        var expected = true;

        //Act
        var actual = sut.HasExternalImage(1249);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(actual.Item1, expected);    
    }    
}
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the mocking framework.

Comment: Wow, Nkosi you're amazing and make it look so easy, this is the missing part I've wanted for ages as I have a large solution to maintain and slowly rewrite.  This is amazing, can't thank you enough